# jsPlumb connection not moving accordingly to element location

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jsplumb

What I'm trying to do is to make a connection between two elements. 
Here is what I have right now.

asp.net:

```
<asp:Button ID="centerCircle" runat="server" CssClass="dependencyCircle centerCircle core" Text="Core Apps" OnClientClick="test2()"></asp:Button>

<asp:Button ID="apiCircle" runat="server" CssClass="dependencyCircle rightCornersB support" Text="APIs" OnClientClick="test()"></asp:Button>
```

jsplumb:

```
jsPlumb.importDefaults({ 

ConnectionsDetachable:false

});
jsPlumb.bind("ready", function () {


var firstInstance = jsPlumb.getInstance({
    PaintStyle: {
        lineWidth: 10,
        strokeStyle: "#567567",
        outlineColor: "black",
        outlineWidth: 1
    },
    Connector: ["Bezier", { curviness: 30 }],
    Endpoint: ["Dot", { radius: 8 }],
});
firstInstance.connect({
    source: "apiCircle",
    target: "centerCircle",
    anchors: ["Left", "BottomRight"],

});
});
```

It generates the connection between the two elements when I run the application, but when I resize the window size and the position of two elements changes, the connection does not move accordingly to the position of two elements. Is there any reason why the connection is not re-adjusting its position accordingly to the position of two elements?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever window is resized you need to tell jsPlumb to repaint all connections since the positions of the elements have changed. **Code:**

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
    jsPlumb.repaintEverything(); //firstInstance.repaintEverything();
});
```